# List of known IP ranges

Tags: ip, routing

I'm looking to find a list of IP range/Owner.
Of course I would enjoy a comprehensive one, but even a "short list" would be OK to start with, as we probably won't be able to set policy regarding small, (to us) unfamiliar owners.

Comment: Will the reverse DNS do it?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/) and their list of [IPv4 Address space](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml) then work out from there to the [RIR](http://www.iana.org/numbers)s and beyond ?